# Query array parameter to Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, query-string

I have this string in my location.search string:

`test[one][]=somestring`

Is there a way to convert this string to javascript like this:

```
{
  "one": ["somestring"]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so... at least not without using `eval`

Comment: Why not have `{
  "one": ["somestring"]
}` in the query string and do a JSON.parse on it?

Comment: Main problem is that if then i want to copy paste the url and send it to someone, this will break and won't be recognized as a link